# reactjs - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type') formik with custom component

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using formik with my custom component.

this is how I am using

```
<Field id="basic-typeahead-single"
    options={this.state.variables}
    labelKey="name"
    selected={this.state.singleSelection}
    placeholder="Choose a Variable" name={`conditions.${index}.variable`}
    component={AutoComplete} />
```

and this is my `AutoComplete` using [Typehead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-typeahead)

```
const AutoComplete = ({ field, form, ...props }) => {
  return <Typeahead
    {...field} {...props}
  />
};
```

this renders the dropdown and on selection of any value it shows

```
Formik.tsx:600 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
    at Formik.tsx:600:1
    at Formik.tsx:653:1
    at Object.onChange (Formik.tsx:1200:1)
    at Typeahead._handleChange (Typeahead.js:358:1)
    at Typeahead.<anonymous> (Typeahead.js:530:1)
    at callCallback (react-dom.development.js:12318:1)
    at commitUpdateQueue (react-dom.development.js:12339:1)
```

what can be the issue? how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had to add `onChange` method and then using `setFieldValue` need to update the value like this

```
onChange={e => {
           if (e && e.length) {
             setFieldValue(`conditions.${index}.variable`, e[0].name)
           } else {
             setFieldValue(`conditions.${index}.variable`, null);
           }
         }}
```